# Global Costmap Implementation

Tags: ros, navigation, costmap, 2d-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Greetings,

I would like to ask if there is a way to create a global costmap for the navigation package from a map that doesnt comply to the 3 color standard ROS expects. This means having a map with extra information, such as elevation and terrain type. Ideally I would like to create the global costmap only once in order to calculate a single global path.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198956/global-costmap-implementation/) by [AndreasLydakis](https://answers.ros.org/users/5125/andreaslydakis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 140 on 2014-12-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The costmap_2d package only accepts a `nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid` type of map into the static_map layer of the costmap. Im assuming the static_map layer is what you are interested in since you want to 'create' a global costmap and then be able to calculate a single global path for the robot to traverse along. However, you must note that the `nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid` is a 2D representation of a grid map (3 colors as you mentioned; known, empty, unknown).

One thing you could do, is set the [voxel grid parameter](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/b384cac812381a9313d7cdc9be9eb272c4fccb38/costmap_2d/launch/example_params.yaml#L20) in your costmap configurations to `true`, so that your data (pointclouds, LIDAR, etc) is represented in 3D; just setup your observation sources to whatever types of sensors you use like in [line 38](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/b384cac812381a9313d7cdc9be9eb272c4fccb38/costmap_2d/launch/example_params.yaml#L38). But i actually am not sure myself if the path planner will plan paths around elevated obstacles (for example like a hanging chandelier) since you only specify 2D footprint of your robot (width and length) but no height. But now that i think about it, i think all the 3D obstacle data gets squashed into a 2D layer anyway (can someone verify this please?).

Another option would be using a [octomap](http://wiki.ros.org/octomap) which is a 3D occupancy grid. Please note, you wont be able to simply input the 3D occupancy grid into the costmap static_layer through the `/map` topic, since the topic sends `nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid` messages as i said above. However i have found a question [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/105331/publishing-from-octomap_server/) which basically states that the octomap_server can already just publish a 2D projection of your 3D occupancy grid, so you can use it with the map_server or costmap static layer.

Hope this helps

---

Originally posted by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) with karma: 1526 on 2014-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0